# How to use Scanner for parsing doubles

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

I have written a code that reads in a file like this:

```
Daan Jansen M     1.78  83
Sophie Mulder    V     1.69  60"
```

It has to give back a result like this:

```
Mr. Johnson’s BMI is 26.2 and is unhealthy.
Mrs. Miller’s BMI is 21.0 and is healthy."
```

This is based on the calculation weight/length2, which are the last two numbers from the inputfile.

After I run the code and select the file, I get the followig error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at BodyMassIndex.BodyMassIndex.readLine(BodyMassIndex.java:28)
    at BodyMassIndex.BodyMassIndex.readFileIn(BodyMassIndex.java:18)
    at BodyMassIndex.BodyMassIndex.start(BodyMassIndex.java:39)
    at BodyMassIndex.BodyMassIndex.main(BodyMassIndex.java:43)
```

I don't get what I am doing wrong. Does anyone  see the problem?

Here is the code of the main class, and the class Person which stores the data form the file.

```
package BodyMassIndex;

import java.io.PrintStream;

class Person {
PrintStream out;

static final char GENDER_MEN = 'M';
static final char GENDER_WOMAN = 'V';
static final double MINIMUM_BMI= 18.5;
static final double MAXIMUM_BMI=25.0;

double length;
int weight;
char gender;
double bmi;
String name;
String surname;
String status;
String call;

Person(double length, int weight,char gender,String name,String surname){
    this.length= length;
    this.weight=weight;
    this.gender= gender;
    this.name=name;
    this.surname=surname;
}

String checkGender(){
    if(gender=='M'){
        call="Mr";
    }
    else{
        call="Mrs" ; 
    }return call;

}

double bmi (){
    double bmi = weight/(length*length);
    this.bmi=bmi;
    return bmi;
    }

void checkHealth(){
    if(bmi >= MINIMUM_BMI && bmi<=MAXIMUM_BMI){
     status= "healthy";
    }
    else{
        status= "unhealthy";
    }

}


void printMethod(String status){
    out.printf("%s",status);
}

}
package BodyMassIndex;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import ui.UIAuxiliaryMethods;

class BodyMassIndex {
PrintStream out;

BodyMassIndex() {
    out = new PrintStream(System.out);
}

void readFileIn() {
    Scanner fileScanner = 
UIAuxiliaryMethods.askUserForInput().getScanner();
    while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
        String information = fileScanner.nextLine();
        readLine(information);
    }
}

void readLine(String information) {
    Scanner personScanner = new Scanner(information);
    while (personScanner.hasNext()) {
        String name = personScanner.next();
        String surname = personScanner.next();
        char gender = personScanner.next().charAt(0);
        double length = personScanner.nextDouble();
        int weight= personScanner.nextInt();
        Person een = new Person(length, weight, gender,name,surname);
        een.bmi();
        een.checkHealth();
        een.checkGender();
        out.printf("%s %s's bmi is %.2f, and is %s \n",een.call, 
een.surname,een.bmi,een.status);
        }

}

void start() {
    readFileIn();
}

public static void main(String[] argv) {
    new BodyMassIndex().start();
}
}
```

Comment: You're checking to see if there's one string, and then reading three, a double and an int.  There's a mismatch between your expected and actual input, so it's blowing up.  You'd probably be better off reading a line at a time, and parsing it yourself.

Comment: As a side note, using the BMI scale is an outdated idealization that never worked well and has major built-in assumptions that are incorrect. But if that's what  you have to use, then I guess you're stuck.

Comment: @azurefrog how do I do the parsing?

Answer (score 1):

The locale of the scanner is the issue or UIAuxiliaryMethods scanner is somehow changing how a line is read.

Depending on the machine it is running on and it's default locale you might be getting seemingly random errors.  For instance GERMAN has "20,7" instead of "20.7".

Your code as it exists works for me.  But if I force the locale then I can get the same exception.

```
void readLine(String information) {
    Scanner personScanner = new Scanner(information);
    personScanner.useLocale(Locale.GERMAN);
    while (personScanner.hasNext()) {
```

You need to force a specific locale that matches the file contents.  In your example this works.

```
    personScanner.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: I tried the useLocale, but it doesn't even recognize the function. I am working in Eclipse.

Comment: This was available as far back as Java 1.7.  It should not matter that it is Eclipse or not.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html